# What is the quickest way to max out my skills?

Tags: fantasy-life

I'm trying to go through and Legend rank all of the lives before I purchase the DLC and right now I am highly frustrated with some of the artisan lives (Specifically [Tailor](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Tailor), [Alchemist](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Alchemist), and [Cook](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Cook)). The only quests I have left for these classes are the ones that require you to max out the life skills (*Sewing Superstar* for the Tailor class, *The Divine Alchemist* for the Alchemist life, and *Egg & Veg Master*, *Meat Master*, *Seafood Master*, and *Cooking Master* for the Cook Life).

What is the most efficient (in regards to time and resources) method to fully max out these skills?

Comment: Find whichever highest recipe you can buy all ingredients for and repeat it with auto complete with max stacks until you run out of resources. Then buy more and repeat until you have it maxed out. It's pretty boring, but gets you decent amount of money and you don't really need to do anything yourself.

Comment: @Chippies What do you mean by "highest recipe"?

Comment: Highest rank craft/recipe, one that gives the most XP, but you can still purchase everything you need in stores without having to farm for stuff.

Comment: You won't benefit much by crafting novice items, is basically what I'm saying.

Comment: Is the highest level craft always the one that gives you the most XP?

Comment: The higher the mastery required, the more XP it gives per craft. If you intend on purchasing the DLC, there's no reason to wait until you get everything to Legendary.

Comment: Yeah, but then I will be able to immediately start working on the God-in-Training ranks.

Comment: You will have to go through the DLC story before you can do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25989/discussion-between-cyberson-and-chippies).